# git Push failed: Failed with error: ssh variant 'simple' does not support setting port

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ssh

My git remote origin uses ssh url with port specified. I am getting an error while pushing using IntelliJ.

**Push failed: Failed with error: ssh variant 'simple' does not support setting port**

I encountered this error after upgrading to latest git 2.16.1

[image: Push failed: Failed with error: ssh variant 'simple' does not support setting port]

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/unable-to-detect-latest-git-changes-ssh-variant-simple-does-not-support-setting-port-943532118.html, it seems like git 2.16 doesn't work with SSH executable bundled with IntelliJ 2017.3.

```
Git version 2.16.0-rc0 does not work well with OpenSSH version 6.7 or older as stated in this bug report.
```

**Changing IntelliJ configuration to use "SSH Executable -> Native" fixed this issue.**

[image: Git Executable to Native]

Comment: Works with following IntelliJ version:
`IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3
Build #IU-171.4424.56, built on May 12, 2017`

Comment: This didn't work in my case (for Android Studio 3.1). Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 22):

I got it solved with setting

`git config --global ssh.variant ssh`

No need to change anything in Android Studio 3.1

Comment: Worked for me on Debian 9 and PyCharm 2017.3.6

Comment: `error: could not lock config file /c/Users/myusername/.gitconfig: No such file or directory`. I tested this before my faulty `git clone ...`   leading to `fatal: ssh variant 'simple' does not support setting port`.

Comment: it looks like you are missing the .gitconfig file

Answer (score 3):

Applies to:

- Windows 7
- IntelliJ Idea 2017.3.4 Build UI-173.4548.28 build on Jan 29, 2018
- git version 2.16.2.windows.1
- ssh -V OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017

---

1) IntelliJ IDEA remove port number from your remote

before: 
   | origin | ssh://myusername@git.mycompany.com:24567/ABC/my.project/project|

after:
   | origin | ssh://myusername@git.mycompany.com/ABC/my.project/project|

2) IntelliJ IDEA leave SSH executable as "Build-in"

3) create ssh config file ~/.ssh/config

```
Host git.mycompany.com
  HostName git.mycompany.com
  Port 24567
  User myusername
```

more details about config see: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/

4) restart IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 1):

> **Applies to**:
>
> - Win10 64bit
> - Android Studio 3.0.1, BUILD #AI-171.4443003
> - Git 2.16.0.windows.2

Solution in my case - **remove port number from your remote** (VCS -> Git -> Remotes), leave Native for SSH executable (File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Git -> SSH executable -> Native).

```
before: ssh://git@192.168.2.46:22/home/git/projects/android/project.git

after: ssh://git@192.168.2.46/home/git/projects/android/project.git}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Android Studio 3.1

I changed **Preferences > Version Control > Git > SSH executable** from **Built-in** to **Native** as suggested here but it didn't help.

Then I upgraded Android Studio to 3.2 and switched back to **Built-in**. It fixed the issue in my case.